# Material nodes grey value of 0.5 results in a numerical value of 0.21

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders, masking, shader-nodes

Why is this the case?

Connect an image texture, generate an image of 0.5 grey scale, connect to map range 0 to 1 TO 0 to 10. Plug that into Wave Texture scale, see the results? A scale of 5 on the wave texture is not the same as half of the range of 0 to 10 from the 0.5 grey.

Is there a way to solve this? I need linearity and predictability when creating a mask in order to control values of a wave texture node.

blender file: https://www.dropbox.com/t/J4nKPGa7FMqQmY5y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the *Color Space* of your image to *Non-Color* (since it's grayscale anyway). Blender gamma corrects sRGB color spaces which messes up the linearity of the scale - non color leaves the values and linearity intact:

[image: ColorSpace]

Comment: I just tried color space XYZ and it seems to be giving perfect 0.5 output while non-color is a tiny bit off. Any danger of using XYZ instead?

Comment: Oh, would you look at that. The error in non-color is due to not using a float type image. XYZ no longer works with float images. Interesting.